# Clojure "map" function ordering guarantees?

Tags: clojure

The doc for `map` says:

```
user=> (doc map)

clojure.core/map
([f] [f coll] [f c1 c2] [f c1 c2 c3] [f c1 c2 c3 & colls])
  Returns a lazy sequence consisting of the result of applying f to
  the set of first items of each coll, followed by applying f to the
  set of second items in each coll, until any one of the colls is
  exhausted.  Any remaining items in other colls are ignored. Function
  f should accept number-of-colls arguments. Returns a transducer when
  no collection is provided.
nil
```

`applying f to the set` makes me unsure about whether `f` is applied to the *sequence* of n-th elements of every collection passed in to give the n-th element of the result sequence.

In other words:

Is there a guarantee that

```
(map str [ "1" "2" "3" ] [ "a" "b" "c" ] )
```

will always return

```
("1a" "2b" "3c")
```

and never

```
("a1" "b2" "3c")
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `(map str ["1" "2" "3"] ["a" "b" "c"])` will always return `("1a" "2b" "3c")`.

From the source code here you can see it calls the function on `(first s1) (first s2)` and then calls `(map f (rest s1) (rest s2))`, so it always processes them in order:

https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L2756

Before it starts it calls `seq` on each of the collections. For an ordered collection like a vector, the elements in the resulting seq will always have the same order as the original collection. For an unordered set, you cannot expect them in a particular order, but that's not the case you're asking about.